# Wrong Date Format (locale) in SQL Server Reporting Services Report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am unable to solve an issue with a report on SSRS.

The scenario is : a link in a Silverlight application loads a new web page containing a Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer control. The parameters for the control are passed in the QueryString to the new page.

If the date is passed as 01/08/2011, when the report is loaded, the date control on the report viewer has the value 08/01/2011 (i.e. it has been converted to American format and my locale is United Kingdom, en-GB).

This only happens in the deployed solution, it works correctly in Visual Studio on my local PC. My IE settings are correct.

I made the following checks on the deployed IIS Server (IIS 6.0):-

The security account for the relevant Application Pool = Network Service.

In the Registry the SID for this user is S-1-5-20 so I checked the registry settings under HKEY_USERS > S-1-5-20 >  Control Panel > International . These were all correctly set for United Kingdom. Although theoretically they should not have an effect I also checked the same settings for Local System (S-1-5-18) and NT-Authority (S-1-5-19) which were identical.

I next checked the Culture and UI Culture on the web site. These were as follows: -

Right-click website - Properties > ASP.NET. 
Click the 'Edit Global Configuration' button to check the server config settings.
Select the Application tab and view the values for Culture and UI Culture.

Both values are set as en-GB. So OK.

Did the same in the 'Edit Configuration' button which is for viewing/editing the specific application's config file.The websites' config file values will supercede the server config file values. These are also OK.

Next I checked the SSRS Server.

Service runs under 'Local System' account.
Registry settings for this account are correct HKEY_USERS > S-1-5-18 >  Control Panel > International.
S-1-5-19 and S-1-5-20 also correct

ReportServer.aspx page directive includes Culture="en-GB"
(e.g. <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportViewerPage" Culture="en-GB"%>)

In code the parameter values are set using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.SetParameters(ms.ReportParameter []) and ms.ReportParameter(name, value, visible) and the parameters are definitely the correct value when they are received at this point by the web app (when I step through in code).

I don't know where to turn next. The one difference I have but I can't imagine it is the problem is that the querystring is URLEncoded on the deployed version but not in the design on my local PC i.e

[server version]
  ...%26END_DATE%3d31%2f07%2f2012+00%3a00%3a00%26START_DATE%3d01%2f08%2f2011+00%3a00%3a00

[local version]

...&END_DATE=31/07/2012+00:00:00&START_DATE=01/08/2011+00:00:00

I would be extremely GRATEFUL for any suggestions that anyone has.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in the date in dd-mmm-yyyy format then it is unabiguous, eg  18-Jan-2011.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I'll try it as soon as I can get chance and let you know if it fixes it.